# UML activity diagram as DSL; converting to C++

Tags: c++, uml, code-generation, dsl

I'm to write an [event correlator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181483/root-cause-analysis-in-event-correlation). A fundamental part of the system will be a huge decision tree that recognizes the origin of the fault basing on recorded states and log files, and one of the primary concerns was keeping that tree maintainable - written in a format easily understandable and editable for the programmer.

Since 7-levels-deep nested if()s is not my idea of "maintainable and easy to understand", I [asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182025/creating-huge-decision-tree) for ideas how to represent it in a form that is a good middle ground between machine-friendly, user-friendly and cost-efficient. The obvious answer was using a Domain-specific language that would be compilable to C++ in which the actual event correlator will be written. The obvious question was how that DSL should look like.

The suggestion I liked best was to use UML activity diagram, and have it compiled to C++. The diagram would likely consist almost strictly of decisions, with activities only at leaves of the tree, as conclusions reached by the decision process. In essence, the diagram is my graphical DSL, which should be then compiled into that huge bunch of if()s in C++. And while I'll still need to craft all conditional functions by hand, at least the interconnections between the conditions should get handled by the system.

Now, what tool should I use for creating that diagram?

Since "roll your own" isn't my idea of cost-efficient, considering it is to ultimately create one, single diagram  for one  device (even if it will likely be edited forever, as new modes of failure are discovered), I had a look at the [List of Unified Modeling Language tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).

Quite a few of these, including these that have "C++" listed in the "Languages generated" but I know the reality is never that good - I'm not interested in a bunch of header files pre-filled with class definitions according to the class diagram. I need a file that contains my decision tree; a bunch of conditional statements with conditions pre-filled with decision functions calls which I'm to write by hand, and outcomes as specific conclusion function calls.

Now my question is which ones can do that, aren't overly difficult to use, and aren't expensive either - free tools preferred but reasonably priced commercial ones are fine too.

Alternatively, failing that - which ones can save that diagram in a form that I could parse with a self-made "compiler", and how to approach creating that compiler.

Of course other suggestions are most welcome too - maybe a tool for old-fashioned flow diagram that can generate such code? Maybe a dedicated DSL to create what I need exists already?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you solution well enough, but it sounds like you are trying to encode your decision tree as a *tree* directly in the UML.  I think you'd be better off to write down an event sequence E1 E2 ... EN -> T for *each separate event*; these are then trivial to inspect as they are completely self-contained, and trivial to insert (just add one) or delete. The set of sequences can be easily composed into a a tree looking for common prefixes of the event chains.  Now you don't even need a heavyweight engine like UML; a pretty simple DSL with named events is enough.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I wouldn't really mind if the generated code is such sequences. Sure it would be far less efficient as many conditions would need to be evaluated multiple times (...unless I create a caching wrapper) - and many of these conditions are quite expensive to calculate (database lookups etc). See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182025/creating-huge-decision-tree for an example of a small piece of the tree that is to be created.

Comment: @IraBaxter: As for doing that at user level, making "E1", "E2" etc descriptive names (easy to understand in order to be easy to modify!) will quickly make it devolve into multi-line strings of conditions... and if a decision in one of the top branches needs to be augmented, I'll have to edit dozens of leaves that are child nodes to that decision.

Comment: OK, so you get a tradeoff: complete separation of concerns by specification of individual event sequences so you never have to think about 2 of them together, or ease of modification in the case of early event common changes. If you have a decision in many sequences at the lower end, you'll have to edit "dozens of leaves" anyway, so it isn't clear your tree scheme really buys you much.  Are these really pure sequenced events?  Or some combination of events in some *partial* order, and some set of conditions (A before B, A before C, system in state E)?

Comment: @IraBaxter: I definitely prefer to think of the events together. The work is usually investigative in nature - narrowing it down by collecting clues. It's almost never "what different sets of symptoms and conditions could indicate module clock is faulty", it's almost always "The module complains it didn't receive new data in timely manner, now which of roughly 6 different reasons caused this kind of fault?" and then analysis of history indicates the data was sent on time, and the module confirmed receiving it, so its complaint less than a second later is baseless and means its clock is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com) can generate C++ code from behavioral diagrams, including Activity Diagrams.  It's offered in several editions; the lowest edition to support behavioral code generation costs $599.  Here's the section of the user guide: [Generate From Behavioral Models](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/software_engineering/code_generation_from_behaviora.html).  Beyond code generation, EA offers [simulation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxXjlPDRGfY&list=UU1IbtSvXDURkqZQf_EpyvgQ&index=5), traceability, and many other niceties.

If you can implement your logic in a Statechart instead, you can use the free [QM Modeler](http://www.state-machine.com/qm/index.php).  It generates C++ code.  It's designed to work with the [QP active object framework](http://www.state-machine.com/qp/), but you can use QM without relying on QP.  (You can also use Enterprise Architect to generate code from Statecharts.)

Answer (score 1):

This URL states that UML is represented as "an XMI format" - a kind of XML based
standard for representing UML.

http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/tamino/ins441/advconc/FromUMLtoXML.htm

If you were to use this standard, your data might be more compatible with the 
other CASE tools:

Most UML tools provide a function to serialize a model into XMI format. XMI is an XML-based industry standard for the exchange of metadata between CASE tools. Because it is XML based, XMI can be converted with the help of XSLT stylesheets into other formats such as XML Schema. An example of such a stylesheet can be found at http://www.aomodeling.org/.

I am guessing this XML could be parsed with an ordinary C++ XML parser such as
Xerces or (for Windows) MSXML /XML DOM.

Comment: Having converted UML to various formats or code using XSLT, XMI is a lousy starting point - it's very verbose and not easy to query. So do a two stage transform - first from XMI to some XML which just has the details you need, then from that format to the generated artefact.